# Fallout Shelter crashing on startup?

Tags: fallout-shelter, android

So this morning I was actually pretty excited to play Fallout Shelter because I had a dweller returning from the wasteland with a lot of loot, aa couple babies being born, an objective that would have been completed and given me a lunchbox, and various other things. But when I turn on the game it gets past the "Bethesda" logo and to the "Please Stand By" screen, and then crashes! The tab is still open in the background, but if I try reopening it it takes me to the beginning of the sequence again.

I'm on running on a Moto X phone, and I've had no troubles with the game in the past. I would prefer not to restart as I was fairly far into the game, plus about to get all that beautiful bounty I previously talked about.

Comment: Did you try turning your phone off and on? Did you try downloading an app killer and using that?

Comment: If you have not done either, the app continues to run in the background when you "close" it. If it crashes, it stays frozen in its crashed state, in the background memory.

Comment: I did try turning the phone back off and on when it happened, but I did not try using an app killer. I can manually close it from running in the background by swiping it away, though, isn't that the same?

Comment: Most likely not. Android is designed to have its apps run permanently in the background, so unless you are using an app provided by Motorola, you are most probably not actually closing the background processes. That said, I find it unlikely that there is a suitable fix, if you have not had a resolution yet. Or rather, I can not see a fix that does not involve resetting the app or the phone.

Comment: Well shoot. I guess I'll wait to see if anyone else has a fix because I'd really prefer not to start over and I'd also like to know what caused this.

P.S. here is what I mean by closing the apps in the background: http://imgur.com/5yLKRNk

Comment: [Check out this little beauty](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller&hl=en), it is what I have always used and recommended for app management. Makes a reportedly big difference if your device has low memory. If you close Fallout Shelter using your method, open up this app immediately, and see it is still there, you may have not closed it entirely. I find a lot of apps open themselves up again, anyway, but have not experienced Fallout Shelter to do so.

Comment: Hey TimeLord, its been a while, but I was wondering: how do you delete saves from the "Fallout Backup" app that you linked to? It says in the app that I have to log on to my Dropbox account to delete/rename saves, but I don't own a Dropbox account. So how do I remove them?

Comment: Just wanted this on the record in the comments. Showing your app list and swiping the app away removes the running app from memory. Things that remain are called Services and must be manually terminated either via a process killer or from the running services list in settings>apps. Not every app has a service associated with it. App killers are prehistoric tools that have long outlived their purpose. Android handles apps much better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of people are experiencing this issue, and I believe there's no way to restore your vault, as the crash happens due to corrupt save file (it becomes 0kb). The only way to play the game again is to reinstall it and start over. But the crashes will still be happening. I was in the same situation as you, and was very frustrated at first... Lost two vaults to these crashes. But there is a solution! =)

Right now I'm using an app to backup the saves, and whenever the game gets corrupted - I simply restore the previous backup. Here's the app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.fosrollback.fosrollback

Just make a backup EACH TIME BEFORE you start the game (don't rely on auto-backup, it's crap). This way if it gets bugged, you will be able to restore it from the closest point. And try to stick to short sessions, the longer you play non-stop - the more chance that it will get bugged.

And don't worry about losing that stuff you had in the old vault. In a few days it will seem unimportant, it will all come back quickly, and much more. Actually there's a bonus to this app (some advice on tactics from my personal experience, don't read further if you prefer learning everything yourself, and making your own mistakes=)). If you wish, you can backup the save before you open a lunchbox, and if it gives you crappy stuff - just restore and open it again=) Repeat untill it gives you some legendary weapon, like Fat Boy, then equip a dweller with it and send him out, packed with as much stimpaks and radaways as possible. He will bring you so much loot, that you will have to build more storages to keep it all=)

Also make sure to keep your dwellers count under 30 (29 idealy), until you gather enough loot, level them up and equip them with good enough weapons. Because when you reach 30 dwellers - the molerats will start digging their way into your rooms, and you'd better be ready for them... And don't build the radio-station, untill you want to grow the population over 29 dwellers.

Comment: lol, just happened to me again) had to restore an hour-old backup)

Comment: so now is the problem, it already chrasehd by me and i bought Mr. Handy five times... what now ;=

Comment: Dang, well I am disappointed that this happened and hope they fix the bug soon, but I think I am ready now to start a new vault. Great answer!

Comment: @Serverfrog , if you made in-game purchases and lost your save to crashes - you ask for a refund as described in this guide: http://www.ibtimes.co.in/fallout-shelter-android-users-suffering-crashes-due-save-data-corruption-bug-guide-get-refund-643159

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me, and I found I could fix by tapping the cloud save button on the vault multiple times.

Comment: This worked for me on two vaults that consistently crashed seconds after loading.